# Not able to get the alert with main viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a One main view controller and in that I am having two sub view controllers named like rightViewcontroller and leftViewcontroller. When we press the menu items from the right view then I am changing the left view controller.That's working fine.Here my problem is If I get any alert that's only fixed to any of the View controller's.Then user able to press the other view which is not having the alert(those are custom alert's. I need custom alerts as per the client requirement)in iPad. Please Help me

Thank's in advance

Comment: Are you saying that an alert is only covering half the view?

Comment: Yes, I have one FirstViewController, In that having two sub view's like iPad settings screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an alert on, say, the `leftViewController`, then disable the user interaction on the other `viewController`s.

something like:

```
rightViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I tried this one but I am not able to get the access of RightViewControler in left. because they both are there in one MainViewController

Comment: ya, this is one solution to it, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you present your alert you are showing it over one of the views like showInView:self.view when in fact you should show it over the parent view so it covers both like showInView:self.navigationController.parentViewController.view (that's just pseudo code).

Without seeing your code you use to present it currently I can't give you exact code.

Another way would be to first get a pointer to the parent view controller or navigation controller and show it there.

Comment: I haven't use navigation controller for developing this app.

Comment: Whichever is the controller that contains both left and right views. You need to show it on that and not on just 1 of the views.

Comment: Thank's for reply.I tried that but I am not able to get that main controller in left or right view controller.

Comment: Maybe if you show us some code, we could help some more. You will be able to get a reference to the parent controller.

Comment: In main View Controller I am doing like this 
{
[view addSubview:rightContainerView];
[view addSubview:LeftContainerView];
[self setView:view];

Comment: In main View Controller I am doing like this 
{
[view addSubview:rightContainerView];
[view addSubview:LeftContainerView];
[self setView:view];
}
so it is showing those view side by side. But those are suppurate viewcontroller view's.Then I have alert's in these two left and right view controller's. When I am showing that they are fixed to respected view controller. I need to show that on top of main View controller and I have to handle the button press of the alert in respected view controller

Comment: Add a property to each to hold a pointer to main, then before adding to main set that property leftContainerView.mainPointer = self, then from each you can ask main to show the alert (put the alert code in main and call it from the subviews)